# django : about subnet address range query

Tags: django, range, ip-address, django-queryset

Hello all,
I am working with mysql & django.

I need some time to query of IP address range. 
example: `10.25.239.0/26`
but, I don't have any idea.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of libraries for dealing with IP addresses. We used [CIDR Block Converter](http://brandon.sternefamily.net/posts/2007/12/python-cidr-block-converter/) with a few tweaks. There's also [Python ip-tools](http://code.google.com/p/python-iptools/) and [several others](http://www.google.com/search?q=python%20cidr).